# In Visual Studio Code, how do you inject clink into the integrated terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was using [clink](http://mridgers.github.io/clink/) with [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/) for various node related tasks on windows, but now I'm trying Visual Studio code.

*How do I inject clink into Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal, so that I can get real command history persistence between sessions, incremental history search, etc.?*

With ConEmu I could inject clink by dropping the clink folder into a specified pickup directory.

I've tried using the path to the included clink bat file, and the clink exe in the VS Code setting `terminal.integrated.shell.windows` but these spawn and then close the command shell immediately.

Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I discovered that you can pass arguments to the integrated shell in Visual Studio Code. Combined with the cmd.exe /K option which *Carries out the command specified by string but remains,* clink can be injected.

In VS Code, go to File > Preferences > Settings or use `Ctrl ,` and add the settings:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\sysnative\\cmd.exe",
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["/K", "C:\\path\\to\\clink\\clink_x64.exe inject"]
```

This is the equivalent of opening a command prompt in Windows, and running `clink_x64 inject`.

Comment: I have to change it to `["/K", "C:\\path\\to\\clink\\clink_x64.exe", "inject"]` (possibly because my path contained spaces), but it worked otherwise \o/

Comment: Note, to open these settings in a json format, choose Open File, then put in: `%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json`  Also to get history to work with clink, pass in the default profile: `, "--profile", "~\\clink"` as two more arguments after `inject`

Answer (score 2):

The use of `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows"` is deprecated.

> This is deprecated, the new recommended way to configure your default
> shell is by creating a terminal profile in
> `#terminal.integrated.profiles.windows#` and setting its profile name
> as the default in `#terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows#`. This
> will currently take priority over the new profiles settings but that
> will change in the future.

This the configuration I used (add this to your `settings.json`):

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "CLink": {
        "overrideName": true,
        "path": "C:/Windows/system32/cmd.exe",
        "args": [
            "/k",
            "FULLPATH/clink.bat",
            "inject",
        ]
    }
},
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "CLink",
```

Comment: Saved me! The top answer is deprecated and does not work with VSCode 1.82.0

Answer (score 0):

It is not answer for your question, but there is another trick to see cmder and text editor in one window. You can open your text editor as another tab in cmder, which I described here:

https://medium.com/@WMorkowski/protip-integrating-cmder-with-text-editor-7f08a6e76de7

from article:

> 1. Run your cmder.
> 2. Go to ‘Settings -> Startup -> Environment’
> 3. Type: set EDITOR_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe alias editor="%EDITOR_PATH%" $1 -new_console:s50V Where
>      in the first line you should type path to your text editor (I was
>      testing it on Visual Studio Code and Sublime, but it should work with
>      other editors).
> 4. Save your settings
> 5. Type ‘editor’ command in command line.
>
> Whoa! We almost finished. But in most cases you don’t want console tab
>   to be attached to the top of the window. You should close console tab,
>   and open it again, paying attention to check “New console split to
>   bottom” checkbox and choose the right console type. Now when you
>   finally set everything up, you should go to ‘Settings -> Startup’, and
>   check “Auto save/restore opened tabs” checkbox to save our new
>   workflow. Now every time you run cmder, your tabs setup will be
>   restored.

Comment: So this actually keeps VS Code _inside_ a cmder tab? That's pretty good if you want to split the window in complex ways.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment:

Open settings.json with:

```
File > Open > %APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json
```

And assuming you installed clink with the magic of chocolatey:

```
choco install clink-maintained
```

Then your clink_x64.exe lives here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\clink\clink_x64.exe
```

And the lines you add to settings.json look like:

```
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\sysnative\\cmd.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
        "/K",
        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\clink\\clink_x64.exe",
        "inject",
        "--profile",
        "~\\clink"
    ],
```

Note the addition of `--profile` ... this allows the history to be persistent between vscode sessions.

Comment: Beware that spaces in the path may break some features of clink (or at least it used to).